# Which one should I use for SEO proposes? <div>text</div> or <img alt=“text” />

Tags: seo, html, css, images, alt-attribute

I know that the `alt=""` attribute is recommended for SEO propososes, but I also heard that put the description inside a `div` and hide with `text-indent:-9999px` or `font-size:0;` is a good practice for SEO.

So there is any difference between use:

```
<img alt="Descripition" />
```

**or**

```
<div style="background: url('path/to/img')>Description</div>"
```

Comment: What is you SEO goal?  Do you want to rank the page in Google web search, or the image in Google image search?   Or both?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller to rank on the google web search.I've been question this when I was hiding a text from a logo, I thought "If I use the <img>, I'll have the description right on the tag and no need to put an text-indent. But must have an difference between an text inside a <div>,"

Comment: Google reads your `font-size:0` and thinks your are spamer:) Such technics is against guidelines - don't do it, not `text-indent:-666`, neither `z-index:-666;`. Write `alt="" title=""` - it should be enough.

Comment: @Evgeniy and about the text-indent, if I want to rank a keywork on an bg image, What I should use for hide my text?... Use text-indent is also bad practice for SEO ?

Comment: There is no way to hide text and have it be used for SEO: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353?hl=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For images that you want to get crawled use the `<img>` tag with a well-written `alt`attribute that describes the image.

For background images solely used for design use the CSS `background-image`.

As far I know CSS rules will not add value to your sites SEO but if CSS is used to hide contents from users and is only visible to search engines that might hurt your sites SEO.

Comment: It's also important to note that google wont include background images in search results